# How to convert numeric to nvarchar in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers, calculated-columns

Consider the following table. I use a trigger to add to the table. In the column of converting the number to the string, it fails.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblAIAgent]
(
    [AgentCode] [NVARCHAR](10) NOT NULL,
    [NationalCode] [BIGINT] NOT NULL 
         CONSTRAINT [DF_tblAIAgent_NationalCode]  DEFAULT ((0)),
    [FirstName] [NVARCHAR](50) NOT NULL 
         CONSTRAINT [DF_tblAIAgent_Name] DEFAULT (''),
    [LastName] [NVARCHAR](50) NOT NULL 
         CONSTRAINT [DF_tblAIAgent_Family] DEFAULT (''),
    [IsActive] [BIT] NOT NULL 
         CONSTRAINT [DF_tblAIAgent_Active] DEFAULT ((1)),
    [Counter] [INT] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_tblAIAgent] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
)

ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[AgentInsert] 
ON [dbo].[tblAIAgent]
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @AgentCode NVARCHAR(10)
    DECLARE @NationalCode BIGINT
    DECLARE @FirstName NVARCHAR(50)
    DECLARE @LastName NVARCHAR(50)
    DECLARE @IsActive BIT
    DECLARE @CounterIs INT

    SET @CounterIs = @@IDENTITY

    SELECT
        @AgentCode = AgentCode,
        @NationalCode = NationalCode,
        @FirstName = FirstName,
        @LastName = LastName,
        @IsActive = IsActive 
    FROM inserted

    INSERT INTO tblAIAgent (NationalCode, FirstName, LastName, IsActive, AgentCode)
    VALUES (@NationalCode, @FirstName, @LastName, @IsActive, 'Agent_' + CAST(@CounterIs AS NVARCHAR(4))) 
END
```

Comment: `@@IDENTITY` doesn't have a value until *after* the insert - so it will be `null` in your example... so if you want to do it that way, which seems overly complex, you'd have to update the `AgentCode` as a separate statement following the insert. Why not just use a computed column? And what are you trying to accomplish using this trigger anyway? It doesn't appear to do anything? And its broken, you can't assume that the `inserted` table will only have a single record in it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a few problems here:

The **[`@@IDENTITY`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/identity-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)** is a system function contains the last identity value that is generated when an `INSERT`, `SELECT INTO`, or `BULK COPY` statement is completed. If the statement did not affect any tables with identity columns, `@@IDENTITY` returns `NULL`. If multiple rows are inserted, generating multiple identity values, `@@IDENTITY` returns the last identity value generated.

In your case, you have an `INSTEAD OF INSERT` trigger, so there is no `INSERT`.

This below query is completely wrong and will gives wrong results, it works as expected only if one row inserted, if there is more than 1 row, then those variables will hold just the values of one row, and you will lose the other values of the other rows, cause the pseudo `INSERTED` may contains 1 or more rows

```
select @AgentCode=AgentCode,
       @NationalCode=NationalCode,
       @FirstName=FirstName,
       @LastName=LastName,
       @IsActive=IsActive 
from inserted
```

Now, looking to your table, you already have an `IDENTITY` column, so you don't need to a `TRIGGER` at all, you can just make a computed column as

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblAIAgent](
    [AgentCode] AS 'Agent_' + CAST([Counter] AS VARCHAR(10)),
    [NationalCode] [bigint] NOT NULL 
    CONSTRAINT [DF_tblAIAgent_NationalCode]  DEFAULT ((0)),
    [FirstName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL 
    CONSTRAINT [DF_tblAIAgent_Name]  DEFAULT (''),
    [LastName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL 
    CONSTRAINT [DF_tblAIAgent_Family]  DEFAULT (''),
    [IsActive] [bit] NOT NULL 
    CONSTRAINT [DF_tblAIAgent_Active]  DEFAULT ((1)),
    [Counter] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_tblAIAgent] PRIMARY KEY ([Counter])
    );
```

---

UPDATE:

According to your comment *"a computed column can no longer be selected as the PK. I want this column to be placed in other relevant tables as a FK.I wrote the trigger to get the column value instead of the computed column so that I can select the column as the primary key"*. You are trying to make it a `PRIMARY KEY` so you can do as

```
CREATE TABLE T(
  Counter INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
  OtherCol INT,
  Computed AS CONCAT('Agent_', CAST(Counter AS VARCHAR(10))) PERSISTED,
  CONSTRAINT PKT PRIMARY KEY(Computed)
);

CREATE TABLE TT(
  ReferenceComputedColumn VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
  OtherColumn INT,
  CONSTRAINT FK_ReferencedComputedColumn 
      FOREIGN KEY(ReferenceComputedColumn) 
      REFERENCES T(Computed)
)

INSERT INTO T(OtherCol) VALUES
(1), (2), (3);

INSERT INTO TT(ReferenceComputedColumn, OtherColumn) VALUES
('Agent_1', 10),
('Agent_3', 20);

SELECT *
FROM T LEFT JOIN TT 
ON T.Computed = TT.ReferenceComputedColumn;
```

**[See how it's working](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=8350b593bd25d88f7b61ce64886771bb)**.

See also this article **[`Properly Persisted Computed Columns`](https://sqlperformance.com/2017/05/sql-plan/properly-persisted-computed-columns)** by **[`Paul White`](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/1192/paul-white)**.

Comment: a computed column can no longer be selected as the PK. I want this column to be placed in other relevant tables as a FK.I wrote the trigger to get the column value instead of the computed column so that I can select the column as the primary key.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(255), @AgentCode)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CAST([PictureId] AS NVARCHAR(4)) From Category
```

Comment: Please edit your answer and use "Sample Code" for greater readability.